# Writing the string.format over multiple lines

Tags: c#

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Name : {0} Date Of Birth : {1: dd/MM/yyyy} Gender : {2} Telephone : {3}", _name, _dob, _gender, _tel);
}
```

How would I change this so that each Heading is written on a separate line so name is on line 1, DOB line 2, Gender line 3, etc?

Comment: look up what `\r` means and `\n` carriage return etc.. simple google search could have yielded you many many resutly

Comment: Do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?. @JimboMountney

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) because you can trust it in different runtimes

```
return String.Format("Name : {1}{0}Date Of Birth : {2: dd/MM/yyyy}{0}Gender : {3}{0}Telephone : {4}",
    Environment.NewLine, _name, _dob, _gender, _tel);
```

Comment: I usually put it as the first argument, as that keeps me from having to move a bunch of them if I make a change.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this approach:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var nl = Environment.NewLine;
    return
        $"Name : {_name}{nl}"
        + $"Date Of Birth : {_dob:dd/MM/yyyy}{nl}"
        + $"Gender : {_gender}{nl}"
        + $"Telephone : {_tel}";
}
```

Or this, if you think it is clearer:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return
        $"Name : {_name}{Environment.NewLine}"
        + $"Date Of Birth : {_dob:dd/MM/yyyy}{Environment.NewLine}"
        + $"Gender : {_gender}{Environment.NewLine}"
        + $"Telephone : {_tel}";
}
```

Comment: You're assuming C# 6.

Comment: @MillieSmith - Correct. That's the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `\r` and `\n` carriage return and linefeed characters.

```
public override string ToString() 
{ 
    return String.Format("Name : {0}\r\nDate Of Birth : {1: dd/MM/yyyy}\r\nGender : {2}\r\nTelephone : {3}", _name, _dob, _gender, _tel); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is a new way in C#
it is very readable and simple to implement;
you should add a dollar sign($) before double qoute:

```
return $"Name : {_name}\r\nDate Of Birth : {_dob}\r\nGender : {_gender}\r\nTelephone : {_tel}";
```